# Preprocessor macro in parent project for use in subproject

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have an Xcode project, which has a subproject which is a static library. I've defined a preprocessor macro in the parent project (in Build Settings), and I want it to be recognized by the subproject at compile time (I have some `#ifdef` statements in the subproject). But the macro is always undefined in the subproject, no matter what I do. Is it possible to do what I want?