# Xcode - How to use build settings(preprocessor macros) of parent project in sub project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, xcode6

I have a static library code which is added as sub project in different projects. Is it possible to know what is the name of parent in static library code for which it is being compiled so that I can edit .This is similar to [Preprocessor macro in parent project for use in subproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470300/preprocessor-macro-in-parent-project-for-use-in-subproject).